Home invasion movie I saw about 7-8 years back
I'm looking for a TV movie that I saw a few years back. It starts as the father and daughter and young son driving down to town from their big house (the father is very rich) and they meet some gangsters (3?) at the shops and they did a rude gesture to the daughter, and she gave them the middle finger, which upset them.
They followed her as her father drove home and they decided to break into the house later. I remember the house has many surveillance cameras and its huge... also I think there's a scene where the father hides something in one of his CD cases in his office/study.

Could be Hostage from 2005: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostage_(film)
"Two teenagers, Dennis and his brother Kevin, and their mysterious accomplice Marshall "Mars" Krupcheck take hostage Walter Smith and his two children, a teenager Jennifer and a young child Tommy, in Smith's house after a failed robbery attempt. [...] She and her brother flee. They lock themselves in the house's panic room. Talley hears the children screaming as they flee."

The film is Hostage from 2005 starring Bruce Willis.
from IMDb:

Jeff Talley, a former LAPD hostage negotiator, has moved himself away
  from his failed career outside of Los Angeles, and away from his wife
  and daughter. When a convenience store robbery goes wrong in his turf,
  the three perpetrators move in on an unsuspecting family. But the
  family's father has a secret which might compromise his kin, and one
  of the criminals is about to jump over the edge. Jeff Talley has to
  get everybody to survive the night......if he can.

And in fact, the father indeed hides a disc with important data in a DVD case in his office.
